# Signing an iframe form to validate its sender

Tags: html, security, post, iframe

I have:

1. A form on static page.
2. Two sites (**A** - the site, where I need to insert this form within iframe, **B** - the site, where I need to verify form and send answer to back to iframe).

I need some kind of singing the form, to be sure, that form was submitted from site **A**. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If the `iframe` is on a different domain, you cannot access the parent from the `iframe` or vice versa. See Same Origin Policy.

Comment: Thank you, but I know that. I need some kind of adding hidden input on the form to be sure that form was sent from **A**.

Comment: Are they on the same domain w/ the same protocol?

Comment: No, they are on different domains

Comment: Then the same-origin policy blocks any communication between the frame (**B**) and the parent (**A**).

Comment: I added `header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://a-host.com');` on the **B** and ajax requests from **A** to **B** are working ok.